# Okhttp + Retrofit @Body request - Transfer-Encoding: chunked added

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I have an issue with using Retrofit and Okhttp in Android. The issue is that the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is automatically added when I am using request with body payload like so:

```
@POST("members")
Observable<Response<Void>> createMember(@Header(X_CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION) 
String clientAuthorization, @Body RequestBody payload);
```

Then, the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is automatically added which for some reason cannot be handled by the server. I want the body to be plain-text json. And the server think its a file I guess.

The worst thing is that If I try to add interceptor and use `removeHeader` that doens't even work.

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
       Request original = chain.request();
       Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
               .removeHeader("Transfer-Encoding");

       Request request = requestBuilder.build();
       return chain.proceed(request);
   }
});
```

I want to be able to send `@POST` with `RequestBody` but without the `chunked` header...

If I use it like so it doesn't add the header:

```
@POST("members")
Observable<Response<Void>> createMember(@Header(X_CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION) String clientAuthorization, @Body **String** payload);
```

But I want to avoid parsing all objects to `String` before sending.

Does anyone have any idea how to remove such request and send objects as plain-text json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Transfer-encoding: chunked` is used when Retrofit doesn’t know the full length of your request body in advance. Ie. when RequestBody.contentLength() returns -1. You’ll need to write some code that converts a RequestBody of unknown length to a RequestBody of known length. You might be able to do this like so:

```
RequestBody original = ...
Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
original.writeTo(buffer);
ByteString bytes = buffer.snapshot();
RequestBody fixedLength = RequestBody.create(bytes, original.contentType());
```

If you do this in an interceptor you don't even need to change the calling code.

Comment: Damn thats how it is. Thank you :)

Comment: In my case I have decided to wrap the body with @SerializedName annotation so that it would be created a little bit differently, like so:
https://nopaste.xyz/?dad65a1065e490d7#vMMtAcsJap3UuNAzl6xu2SKK8HTvOviNjb6G0FrYfyo=